# Advice a humidity sensor with I²C interface

Tags: sensor, i2c, humidity

I like to interface a humidity sensor over the I²C bus.

It should come in a small package, and consume little power. Accuracy isn't that important. I'm using the [DS1621](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/2737) as temperature sensor, I'd like something similar, but for a humidity sensor.

After looking for modules with my criteria, I came across the [HYT271](http://www.hygrosens.com/en/products/sensor-elements/digital-humidity-sensors/hyt-271-allround-talent.html), but that thing is ridiculously expensive. The low-cost version [HYT371](http://www.hygrosens.com/en/products/sensor-elements/digital-humidity-sensors/hyt-371-inexpensive.html) has about the characteristics I'd need, but it's currently not available from my dealer of choice...

I need something reasonable accurate for ambient temperature measuring, and at the same time not too expensive. Should be in the range of a few euros.
*(Bonus points if those chips can be sampled)*.

Answer (score 1):

[Sensirion](http://www.sensirion.com/) has combined temperature/humidity sensors. Their [SHT21](http://www.sensirion.com/en/01_humidity_sensors/05_humidity_sensor_sht21/00_humidity_sensor_sht21.htm) and [SHT25](http://www.sensirion.com/en/01_humidity_sensors/05_humidity_sensor_sht25.htm) have an I2C interface. Both come in a small DFN-6 package.

Comment: DFN-6 is a bit tiny for manual soldering. But I'll take a look at the other package options.

Comment: SHT25 looks really interesting, but it's like not available whatsoever. I guess I'd have to wait till engineering samples become available. Accuracy wise, this thing should be excellent.

Comment: Just tried to sample the SHT21: Nope, they're not gonna send me one to my private address. They might send them to my university, though. But it seems you may order just one at a time...

Answer (score 0):

I believe BME280 by Bosch is perfect for your purposes.

https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/environmental-sensors/humidity-sensors-bme280/